# Replace merged fields with space in converting Word Template to PDF using C#

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that is replacing the merge fields in Word template with the value I pass to it. My problem is when the field is empty it shows the name of the merge field in the PDF file. I need to show nothing when there is no value.

For example in word document I have:

```
 Street Address:    «ADDRESS»

 Apt / Suite:       «APT»
```

When the APT is empty I do not need to show «APT» in my pdf just empty space.

This is my code:

```
    if (documentData.ADDRESS != string.Empty && fieldName == "ADDRESS")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();

                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(documentData.ADDRESS);
                }


                if (documentData.APT != string.Empty && fieldName == "APT")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();

                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(documentData.APT);
                }
```

I am dding this line and it took care of it but not sure if that is a right way to do as I have so many fields so I have to add so many if statement just to replace it with empty for each field.

```
           if (documentData.APT != string.Empty && fieldName == "APT")
                {
                    myMergeField.Select();

                    wordApp.Selection.TypeText(documentData.APT);
                }
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you explicitly exclude `string.Empty`?

Comment: The code looks ok. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @filmor No, but even if I took that out again it shows it in the pdf as this existed in word template I need to somehow replace it with empty space but now sure now.